# Swift: Determining if cast to integer from string succeeds

Tags: swift, casting

Below is my code

```
func contactForUpdates() -> Int {
    //contact server for most recent version
    let versionURL = settings.versionURL

    if let url = URL(string: versionURL) {
        do {
            let contents = try NSString(contentsOf: url, usedEncoding: nil)
//NEXT LINE IS WHERE THE QUESTIONS LIES
            return Int(contents as String)!
        } catch {
            // contents could not be loaded
            processError("Current version could not be loaded.")
            return Int(0)
        }
    } else {
        // the URL was bad!
        processError("Current version could not be loaded--URL was bad.")
        return Int(0)
    }
}
```

If the URL loads, it will return a single integer. A bad internet connection, such as an airport that requires a login prior to internet access, will not return an integer, but a full HTML page that requests a login. forcing a downcast with `return Int(contents as String)!` will produce the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

I assumed that this would run the catch statement when I wrote this, but instead it returns a fatal error. How can I catch this?

Comment: This is not directly answering the question, but I suggest for something like this you consider using a network Reachability library. It will catch other network reachability problems you might not have thought of, and can do things like asynchronously trigger your version check when the network does become reachable.

There are many on Cocoapods. Many are block-based, so instead of having a method like the one you wrote, you move the code from your success case to inside the block that you pass the Reachability library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `0` represents an error for you, you could do:

```
return Int(contents as String) ?? 0
```

`??` is called the "nil coalescing operator". It returns the first value if it's not `nil`, otherwise it returns the second value.

If you want more robust handling you could use `guard`…

```
guard let value = Int(contents as String) else {
    processError("Something went horribly wrong")
    return 0
}

return value
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are forcing an optional value to be non optional.

You have to check if the conversion is possible:

```
if let number = Int(contents as String) {
    return number
}
return -1 // Or something you will recognise as error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func contactForUpdates() -> Int {
    //contact server for most recent version
    let versionURL = settings.versionURL

    if let url = URL(string: versionURL) {
        do {
            let contents = try NSString(contentsOf: url, usedEncoding: nil)
            if let vers = Int(contents as String) {
                return vers
            }
            else {
                processError("Current version could not be loaded--Possibly proxy interception")
                return Int(0)
            }
            //return Int(contents as String)!
        } catch {
            // contents could not be loaded
            processError("Current version could not be loaded.")
            return Int(0)
        }
    } else {
        // the URL was bad!
        processError("Current version could not be loaded--URL was bad.")
        return Int(0)
    }
}
```

Fixes the error, although makes the do/catch run the catch statement. I am not sure why? I hope that somebody can answer that, but otherwise this statement fixes it.

Comment: Inside the `catch` block, Swift gives you an `error`. You can try `print("Error: \(error)")` to see what the problem is.